# Is there a shorter way to write this Jquery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I need to preselect a dropdown option with a certain value, I can use this:

```
$('select option[value="123"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

but if I need to preselect an option based on the text it contains I need to do all this:

```
        $('select option').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.text() == 'My Text') {
                $this.attr('selected', 'selected');
            }
        });
```

Is there a way to do it without looping through all the option tags like the first way but based on text instead of value?

Comment: One waty or the other it's probably better to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` nowadays.

Comment: For the first case, why wouldn't you just do `$("select").val("123")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `:contains()` selector.

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

```
$('select option:contains("My Text")').prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: @JaredFarrish, Your `<input>` tags don't contain anything.  For those, you can use `[value]`.

Comment: I'd never tried to use that on `select` fields (for some reason I initially typed `input`, so yeah). The docs on that are a little "sparse".

Answer (score 1):

Use the [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector. Eg:

```
$('select option:contains("My Text")').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `filter()` which I think will be faster than the `:contains` selector:

```
$('select option')
  .filter(function(){ return $(this).text() === 'my text' })
  .prop('selected', true)
```

Comment: Alright, check this out: http://jsperf.com/contains-vs-filter/3 In Chrome, I get the last two are fastest, sometimes tied, sometimes the last is fastest. Also, you have a subtle flaw in your anonymous function.

Comment: I made sure and ran them first to make sure they weren't frontrunning on accident. Note, splitting the selector on the initial selection was always faster in Chrome than `$('select option')`.

Answer (score 0):

Putting `:contains` aside

```
$('select option').each(function() {
    this.selected = this.text == 'lol2'
});
```